# Displaying total number as pin text for multiple pins at the same location

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Let's say you have multiple pins at the same location or very close. Instead of displaying several very close pins I want to display a single pin with pin count. Is this possible?

Here's an example:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out MarkerClusterer: http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/

It appears to do exactly what you want. For example:
http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/examples/advanced_example.html